# Iterating through a List to find for a permission

Tags: android, list, permissions, iteration, loops

I currently trying to iterate through a list to find a certain permission from all the installed application on the phone, can someone tell me the correct way to iterate through the list?

```
public void getPermissions(Context context) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    final List<PackageInfo> apps = context.getPackageManager()
        .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

    for (PackageInfo pi : apps) {
        String[] permissions = pi.requestedPermissions;
        if (permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                Log.d("TAG", permission);
                            if (permission.equals("android.permission.INTERNET")) {

                                String appname=pi.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString();
                                ImageView appicon;

                                appicon = pi.applicationInfo.setImageDrawable(packageManager);
                                Log.e("TAG", "Permission found for "+ appname);

                                internetArray.add(appname);
                            }
            }
        }
    }
```

} //end of getPermissions method

EDIT: I have managed to get working and display in an arraylist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void getPermissions(Context context) {
     PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
     final List<PackageInfo> apps = context.getPackageManager()
         .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

     for (PackageInfo pi : apps) {
         String[] permissions = pi.requestedPermissions;
         if (permissions != null) {
             for (String permission : permissions) {
                 Log.d("TAG", permission);
                 if (permission.equals("android.permission.INTERNET")) {
                     // do something
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the icon into the arraylist like how i did it with the package name? I manage to save the list of applications and save it into an arraylist and display it, but would it be possible for me to show the icon as well?

Comment: @dythe I know it is long ago, but this might help someone else. The `PackageInfo` has `ApplicationInfo` and within that is `LoadLogo, LoadIcon`. That should return the drawable for the application